# Could PyScript be used as dash clientside callback instead of javascript clientside callback?

Tags: javascript, python, pyscript

`PyScript` has been just released recently [here](https://pyscript.net). Could it be used instead of javascript as a dash clientside callback?

I am showing here an example of clientside callback using javascript where it changes the yaxis' scale from linear to log scale.
This function has one Output (plotly graph as dcc.Graph) and two Inputs (dcc.Store and dcc.RadioItems).
I know how to write a similar clientside function in PyScript. However, I don't know how to use those dash components as Output and Inputs!

To implement PyScript in `html`, I usually add the tag `<pyscript>` then I can insert my function. But how could I implement this through dash clientside function and how to use dash components as Output and Inputs?

I greatly appreciate if someone can simply show me how to replace the `javascript` clientside callback in this example below to `PyScript` clientside callback. Thanks in advance!

````
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import pandas as pd

import json

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')

available_countries = df['country'].unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='clientside-graph'
    ),
    dcc.Store(
        id='clientside-figure-store',
        data=[{
            'x': df[df['country'] == 'Canada']['year'],
            'y': df[df['country'] == 'Canada']['pop']
        }]
    ),
    'Indicator',
    dcc.Dropdown(
        {'pop' : 'Population', 'lifeExp': 'Life Expectancy', 'gdpPercap': 'GDP per Capita'},
        'pop',
        id='clientside-graph-indicator'
    ),
    'Country',
    dcc.Dropdown(available_countries, 'Canada', id='clientside-graph-country'),
    'Graph scale',
    dcc.RadioItems(
        ['linear', 'log'],
        'linear',
        id='clientside-graph-scale'
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Details([
        html.Summary('Contents of figure storage'),
        dcc.Markdown(
            id='clientside-figure-json'
        )
    ])
])


@app.callback(
    Output('clientside-figure-store', 'data'),
    Input('clientside-graph-indicator', 'value'),
    Input('clientside-graph-country', 'value')
)
def update_store_data(indicator, country):
    dff = df[df['country'] == country]
    return [{
        'x': dff['year'],
        'y': dff[indicator],
        'mode': 'markers'
    }]

## Clientside Callback
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(data, scale) {
        return {
            'data': data,
            'layout': {
                 'yaxis': {'type': scale}
             }
        }
    }
    """,
    Output('clientside-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('clientside-figure-store', 'data'),
    Input('clientside-graph-scale', 'value')
)


def update_graph_scale(data, scale):
    return {
        'data': data,
        'layout': {
            'yaxis': {'type': scale}
        }
    }




@app.callback(
    Output('clientside-figure-json', 'children'),
    Input('clientside-figure-store', 'data')
)
def generated_figure_json(data):
    return '```\n'+json.dumps(data, indent=2)+'\n```'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
````

Comment: Your code does not show any JavaScript. Your code runs server side and not client side. The code that Dash generates runs in the browser. Since you are using a framework, the framework would need to be modified to run in a browser.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for the response, but I am not sure if I got what you mean by no clientside callback. As you can see above the callback to change the yaxis' scale is a clientside_callback and is written in JavaScript. it has one output (clientside-graph) and 2 inputs (clientside-figure-store and clientside-graph-scale). Is it clear for you now, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Run your code. Then in the browser, look at the source code. Your code is running at the server and is generating code that then runs in the browser. Those two small snippets of JavaScript could be rewritten into Python, but your backend framework knows nothing about interfacing with Python. I also see no benefit in converting JavaScript to Python in this example. You would need to load 20 MB of code to replace 20 bytes of JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with you @JohnHanley that there is no benefit from converting this particular function from JavaScript to PyScript. I am just showing it here as an example for simplicity. I already have another complicated one in Python which is running heavily on the server side making a slow callback each time it is called. So, to make my app faster, I would like to have it on the clientside, However, I don't know much about JavaScript. So, conversion to PyScript is my best option for now. I'm just wondering how to establish interfacing between PyScript and dash components as inputs/outputs?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what is possible. You would need to modify Dash to interoperate with PyScript. That would require rewriting Dash. There is no simple way to achieve your goal.